# GTFS based Transit Planning using PGRouting

Tags: gis, postgis, gtfs, pgrouting, opentripplanner

I have followed below tutorial for setting-up OpenTripPlanner by importing GTFS data and it worked.

http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Basic-Tutorial/

But I have to integrate the trip planning on an existing GIS implementation which uses OpenLayers, PostgreSQL, PostGIS and PGRouting. I am not sure is it possible to use OpenTripPlanner APIs to fetch Trips and display on GUI.

I would like to know, Is it possible to do the trip planning similar to OpenTripPlanner using PostGIS and Pgrouting (Without using OpenTripPlanner)?

If possible how will be the Pgrouting database structure or query logic for finding upcoming trips between stops with transits?

In Pgrouting DB, found two tables POI and spatial reference table other than ways and vertices, do I need to import GTFS data to this POI and spatial reference table?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

pgRouting and OTP are two different platforms with their own respective tools for importing data into their routing engines.  I'm not sure how it would make sense to try to integrate the two instead of merely using one in favor of the other.  If you're set on using pgRouting, I'd recommend following the [tutorials for loading data into pgRouting](http://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/pgRouting-concepts.html#id42).  Also, for loading transit it does look like pgRouting has the [gtfs2pgrouting](https://github.com/pgRouting/gtfs2pgrouting) tool, but it was last updated 8 years ago.